# Error in python code (IndexError: list assignment index out of range) Beginner level

Tags: python

While running the following code

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []

# write your for loop here
for index in range(len(names)):
    usernames[index] = names[index].lower().replace(" ", "_")


print(usernames)
```

this error is observed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main3.py", line 47, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_kncqjadnfl/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_kncqjadnfl/studentMain.py", line 1, in <module>
    import usernames
  File "/tmp/vmuser_kncqjadnfl/usernames.py", line 6, in <module>
    usernames[index] = names[index].lower().replace(" ", "_")
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `usernames.append(names[index].lower().replace(" ", "_"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most errors speak for themselves.

Your list `usernames` is initialized as empty, that is, of length 0. So whatever integer `index` is, `usernames[index]` will try to access a nonexistent element. That's why you get an `IndexError`.

What you want to do is to append elements to a list `usernames`. `append` method does that. So your for-loop should read:

```py
for index in range(len(names)):
    usernames.append(names[index].lower().replace(" ", "_"))
```

Try reading any python-beginner's tutorial about lists, or at least [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set `usernames[index]` is invalid , as it an empty list but you are writing a value to `usernames[0]`. You can try the below format:

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []

# write your for loop here
for index in range(len(names)):
    print(index)
    usernames.append(names[index].lower().replace(" ", "_"))


print(usernames)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of approaches to get List all the name with an underscore(_)

1. Get all the name with the same case

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []

for index in names:
    usernames.append(index.replace(" ", "_"))

print(usernames)
```

2. If you want to small letter just replace this line

`usernames.append(index.lower().replace(" ", "_"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try This optimized code:

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = [val.lower().replace(" ", "_") for val in names ]
print(usernames)
```

Output:

```
['joey_tribbiani', 'monica_geller', 'chandler_bing', 'phoebe_buffay']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this breakdown solution for iterating over a list of username and making some modification(like lowering the initial case and replacing the middle white-space to underscore("_");

```
Input:

usernames = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
    
# write your for loop here

       for index in range(len(usernames)):
           usernames[index] = usernames[index].lower().replace(" ","_")
           username = usernames[index]
                
    
    print(usernames)

Output:

['joey_tribbiani', 'monica_geller', 'chandler_bing', 'phoebe_buffay']
```